# Why $\kappa = 8 \pi G$ in $D$ dimensional spacetimes?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, conventions, spacetime-dimensions, physical-constants

Probably another question without an answer!  ;-)

In most books/papers I saw on General Relativity, everybody writes $\kappa = 8 \pi G_D$ in the right part of Einstein's equation, even for spacetimes of dimensionality $D \ne 4$ (the minus sign is just a matter of convention):
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
G_{\mu \nu} + \Lambda_D \, g_{\mu \nu} = -\, 8 \pi G_D \, T_{\mu \nu}.
\end{equation}
I understand that we could always *define* $G_D$ so we can write $8 \pi$ in front of it.  But it's not "natural", since $\Omega_3 = 4 \pi$ is the ***solid angle in flat space of dimension 3***.  In general:
\begin{align}\tag{2}
\Omega_{2 n} &= \frac{1}{(n - 1)!} \, 2 \pi^n, \qquad
&\Omega_{2 n + 1} &= \frac{2^{2 n} \, n!}{(2 n)!} \, 2 \pi^n.
\end{align}
For examples: $\Omega_1 = 2$, $\Omega_2 = 2 \pi$, $\Omega_3 = 4 \pi$, $\Omega_4 = 2 \pi^2$.  So it would be more natural to write this, in Einstein's equation (I know, it looks awefull, but it has more sense!):
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
G_{\mu \nu} + \Lambda_D \, g_{\mu \nu} = -\, 2 \, \Omega_{D - 1} \, G_D \, T_{\mu \nu}.
\end{equation}
Notice that Newton's constant has a dimension that depends on $D$ (since $G_{\mu \nu} \sim \mathrm{L}^{-2}$ and $T_{\mu \nu} \sim \mathrm{L}^{-D}$ in cartesian-style coordinates):
\begin{equation}\tag{4}
G_D \sim \mathrm{L}^{D - 2}.
\end{equation}
That constant has a *conformal weight*! (it's also true for the *fine structure constant* by the way: $\alpha \sim \mathrm{L}^{D - 4}$, if you write Maxwell equation in $D$ dimensional spacetime).

So my questions are these:

> Why use $G_D = \kappa / 8 \pi$ instead of $G_D = \kappa / 2 \, \Omega_{D-1}$? (it obviously doesn't give the same constant when $D \ne 4$!).  $\kappa = 8 \pi G_D$ may be simpler than $\kappa = 2 \, \Omega_{D - 1} \, G_D$, but it doesn't make physical sense!
>
> What is the meaning of the factor $2$ in $\kappa = 2 \, \Omega_{D - 1} \, G_D$ (for any $D$)?  Is it related to the ***graviton's spin***? (it is not given by $2 s + 1$ or $s (s + 1)$).  In the special case of $D = 4$, what is the interpretation of that factor in $8 \pi G_4 = 2 \cdot 4 \pi G_4$?
>
> In - very - hypothetical spacetimes with many timelike dimensions, what should be the natural expression for $\kappa$?  For example, for $D = 4$ and metric signature $\eta = (1, 1, -1, -1)$ (two timelike dimensions, two spacelike dimensions), should we write $\kappa = 2 \cdot 2 \pi G_4$ instead of the usual $\kappa = 8 \pi G_4$?

I'm pretty sure nobody would have an answer to these "idiotic" questions.  I'm asking them anyway, in case someone else is crazy enough to scratch his/her head like me!  ;-)

Comment: I don't see any real physics here. Which prefactor we assign to $G_D$ is entirely conventional, and the factors involving $\pi$ are simply due to mismatched conventions between Newtonian physics and GR, cf. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/71636/50583. The belief that any of the other choices for $G_D$ is objectively "more natural" does not strike me as useful, especially since people are still free to set (by choice of units) whatever multiple of $G$ to unity they like. There is no deep physics in the choices for dimensionful constants, cf. also https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.2040.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I don't agree.  In flat space, the elliptic equation part of Poisson's equation do make the $4 \pi$ apparent, in front of $G$.  That solid angle is important.  In curved space, that $4 \pi$ can be defined from the tangent space, as a limit of a very small region in curved space (the solid angle doesn't depend on the size of the region considered).  In $D > 4$, the solid angle is different than in $D = 4$ and should be taken into account, in the elliptic part of Poisson's equation (weak field case).

Comment: I don't want to pick sides here, just wanted to point to a footnote in Ortin's Gravity and Strings, that seems to share the discomfort for this convention. In the second edition of the book, in page 73, at the end of section 3.1.1, footnote 6: "This is an unfortunate convention in the literature in which the factor $4\pi$, which is appropriate for rationalized units in four dimensions, is indiscriminately used in all dimensions.". This book also discusses the implications for Newton's constant in arbitrary dimensions, if only with the books own conventions which you may or may not dislike.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, an example that shows the relative importance of the solid angle.  In Schwarzschild coordinates, we have this metric component: $g_{00} = 1 - \frac{2G M}{r}$.  Absorbing the solid angle in $G$ would give $g_{00} = 1 - \frac{2 G' M}{4 \pi r}$, which is horrible (and $4 \pi r$ is not even an area)!  The $4 \pi$ factor in Einstein's equation is a "chauvinistic" reference to our 3 space dimensions.

Comment: "Horrible" is just your personal aesthetic (which I am inclined to share, btw). The formula works either way, so I'm not sure what *objective* answers to this question you expect.

Comment: @ACuriousMind, well, I agree that it's a matter of "convention", and I personnaly still use $\kappa = 8 \pi G_D$ (instead of $\kappa = 2 \, \Omega_{D - 1} \, G_D$).  But that factor really has something to say about the physics.  We may miss something by not taking care of the solid angle.  I'm sure (my guts are telling me!) that the extra-factor of $2$ has something to say, but I don't know what (is it related to spin?).

Comment: This paper might be of interest: "Normalization conventions for Newton’s constant and the Planck scale in arbitrary spacetime dimension," https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0609060. Notice the word "conventions" in the title.

Comment: @DanYand, WOW!  That paper appears to be extremelly interesting, thanks a lot!  +1.  Apparently, in that previous paper, the $\mathrm{Vol}(\mathbb{S}^{d - 2})$ (volume of the unit $d - 2$ sphere) is the same as the solid angle $\Omega_{D - 1}$, isn't?  The author is extracting an extra $\frac{D - 2}{D - 3}$ factor from $G_N$.  Apparently, this is the $2$ factor in $D = 4$.  The limiting cases $D = 2$ and $D = 3$ are interesting, since it is well known that geometry and matter decouples in these cases.  Also, when $D \gg 4$, we get $\kappa \approx \Omega_D \, G_D \rightarrow 0$!

Answer (score 2):

$$ G_{\mu \nu} + \Lambda g_{\mu \nu} = 8 \pi G \, T_{\mu \nu}. $$

This answer is, admittedly, copied from the USENET group *sci.physics.research* and from an [answer 23 years ago from Daryl McCullough](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.physics.research/c/9yRJKOwSXKc/m/mYT8hGx-7KAJ) regarding that factor of "$2$" in $8 \pi G = 2 \cdot 4 \pi G$

---

Jan 20, 2000, 3:00:00 AM

*baez@galaxy.ucr.edu* (John Baez) says...

> Yeah, I think Ted Bunn explained it. The $4 \pi$ comes from the area of the sphere, just like electromagnetism. The extra factor of $2$ comes from the fact that $h_{00}$ is $-2$ times the Newtonian gravitational potential $\Phi$.

I thought that the source of this $2$ is the square-root appearing in the proper time formula:

$$ \mathrm{d}T = \sqrt{g_{\mu \nu} \, \mathrm{d}x^{\mu} \, \mathrm{d}x^{\nu}}$$

In weak, time-independent gravitational fields, $g_{\mu \nu}$ takes the form

$$ \begin{align}
g_{0 0} &= 1 + h \\
g_{1 1} &= -1 \\
g_{2 2} &= -1 \\
g_{3 3} &= -1 \\
g_{\mu \nu} &= 0  \qquad \text{for } \mu \ne \nu \\
\end{align}$$

So the formula for proper time becomes (using $\left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{dx^1}{dx^0}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dx^2}{dx^0}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dx^3}{dx^0}\right)^2$)

$$\mathrm{d}T = \sqrt{1 + h - \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2} \ \mathrm{d}t$$

For $A$ and $v$ small, we can expand the square-root to get

$$\mathrm{d}T = \left(1 + \tfrac12 h - \tfrac12 \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2 \right) \  \mathrm{d}t$$

The equations of motion for a test particle are obtained
by maximizing the integral $\int \left(1 + \tfrac12 h - \tfrac12 \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2\right) \  \mathrm{d}t$.
Since the constant $1$ is irrelevant for the equations of
motion, this is the same as maximizing the integral $\int D \, \mathrm{d}t$, where

$$ D = \tfrac12 h - \tfrac12 \left(\frac{v}{c}\right)^2 $$

But, in this limit (small $A$ and small $v$), Newtonian mechanics can be used, so we should ***also*** be able to obtain the equations of motion by minimizing the integral $\int L \, \mathrm{d}t$, where

$$ L = \tfrac12 m v^2 - m \Phi $$

(where $\Phi$ is the Newtonian gravitational potential).

This suggests that $D$ and $L$ are linearly related. The only way for this to be true is if

$$ h = 2 \frac{\Phi}{c^2} $$

Comment: In other words, you say that the "2" in $\kappa = 2 \cdot 4 \pi G$ comes from the "2" in the metric $ds^2$, which is a way of saying that the *metric tensor* is a rank 2 tensor (since there's $\mathbf{d}x^{\mu} \otimes \mathbf{d}x^{\nu}$ in it).  This is an implicit way of saying that the gravitational field has spin $s = 2$.

Comment: Yes, that is what I believe McCullough is saying in his *sci.physics.research* post (I linked it above).  In another neophyte question of mine, I am trying to make the case that Planck units (time, length, mass, charge) should be *"rationalized"* to satisfy: $$\begin{align}
c&=1\\
\hbar&=1\\
4\pi G&=1\\
\epsilon_0&=1\\
\end{align}$$
This makes the elementary charge $e=\sqrt{4\pi\alpha}=$0.302822 and I think it should be $4\pi G$ that is normalized rather than $8\pi G$ to normalize *both* the speed of propagation and the characteristic impedance of EM and gravitational radiation.